# import-contol.xml inclusion in checkstyle not working with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I have the `checkstyle.xml` file and in the same directory is the file `import-contol.xml`. The following notification is generated in Intellij (using the plugin):

> The Checkstyle rules file could not be parsed. cannot initialize
> module com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker - cannot initialize
> module
> com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.imports.ImportControlCheck -
> illegal value 'import-control.xml' for property 'file' The file has
> been blocked for 60s.

The checkstyle.xml file contains the following

```
<module
    name="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.imports.ImportControlCheck">
    <property name="file"
        value="import-control.xml" />
    <property name="path" value="^.*[\\/]src[\\/]main[\\/].*$" />
</module>
```

Where the file is included. I have tried a few things without success. What would be the correct value for the property.